# Do not show Checked Icon On Material Components Chip Android

Tags: android, material-design, android-chips

Edit: I managed to make it work by setting the below attirbutes in styles.xml like so:

```
  <android.support.design.chip.Chip
                    android:id="@+id/chipFollowing"
                    style="@style/ChipCustomStyle" ...>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="ChipCustomStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action">
    <item name="checkedIconEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="checkedIcon">@null</item>
</style>
```

Leaving it here in case anyone runs into the same WTF :)

---

Original question:

I don't want to show checked icon on my Chip. I tried setting

```
        app:checkedIcon="@null"
        app:checkedIconVisible="false"
```

both in Chip and ChipGroup element. It won't even compile :/

When I set it on Chip element, I am getting:
error: attribute 'com.companyname.projectname:checkedIconVisible' not found.

Here is my Chip XML:

```
            <android.support.design.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chipFollowing"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/ChipFilledUncheckedText"
                app:checkedIcon="@null"
                app:checkedIconVisible="false"
                app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/bg_chip_state_list"
                app:chipText="@string/chip_following" />
```

I am using Material Components from the 28 Support Library version. Am I missing something obvious? :/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I managed to make it work by setting the below attirbutes in styles.xml like so:

```
  <android.support.design.chip.Chip
                    android:id="@+id/chipFollowing"
                    style="@style/ChipCustomStyle" ...>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="ChipCustomStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action">
    <item name="checkedIconEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="checkedIcon">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just use setCheckable and setCheckedIconVisible

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
KeyValueSelectedEntity letter = array.get(i);
if (getContext() != null) {
    Chip chip = new Chip(getContext());
    chip.setId(letter.getId());
    chip.setText(letter.getName());
    chip.setTag(i);
    chip.setCheckable(true);
    chip.setCheckedIconVisible(false);
    chip.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean selected) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged");
            int tag = (int) compoundButton.getTag();
            ...
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your app theme from `Theme.AppCompat.` to `Theme.MaterialComponents.`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="chipIconTint">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```